# tar .svn folders preserver directory structure

Tags: linux, svn

What I need is to extract all .svn-folders from a project within their original directory structure and make a tar file out of it. So that in the archive I have only the emtpy folders with all .svn-folders and their contents in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using tar a bit like cpio, by selecting directories using find.  EG:

```
find . -name .svn -print | tar --create --files-from - > /tmp/stuff.tar
```

If you want, you can avoid problems with whitespace using -print0 instead of -print, and tar --null.

Comment: That's a good start, but I actually want all the contents of the .svn-directories to be within that tar-file.